# Low level description of input assignments to a function

Tags: c

I want to understand at low level how an input is given to a function. What exactly happens once a function runs? For example, consider the following:

```
int foo(int t1, int t2)
{  
  Function defintion goes here  
}
```

Then later in the code

```
main()
{
  .
  .
  int a= foo(23, 24);
  . 
  .
 }
```

Suppose the code is compiled successfully and we get a binary file, i.e an .exe file corresponding to our high level source code. I want to understand at what level the inputs are given to functions internally and what exactly happens when we double click on this .exe file. What softwares/hardwares come into play after clicking the .exe? I will appreciate if some can give me a brief description.

**As requested**

O.S: Windows
CPU: Intel Core2Duo

Comment: You are asking far, far too much to be answered here. If this is on Windows, please read about PE files and the windows loader and x86 function calls. If this is Linux, read about Elf files and the Linux loader.

Comment: @gpuguy This question would be fine if you can name one exact OS, and which compiler that is used. Otherwise the question may be far too broad for anyone to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I agree with Jonathon.  You also want to look into something called a "call stack".

Comment: What you are asking is almost impossible to explain in brief, and the answers will vary from platform to platform. To get an overview of these things you can take a short course on assembly programming and computer architecture.

Comment: @Panzercrisis You can't assume that a "generic computer" even has a stack.

Comment: Read about compilers, machine code, Application execution by OS various segments of executables like Code Segment , Stack segment etc. Infact this requires a lot of reading nobody can be brief about this.

Comment: @Lundin I guess that's true.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the function calls go, first, the literals `23` and `24` are loaded into specific registers in your CPU (registers used for function parameters). Then, your code jumps to a section when the function `foo` is located.

`foo` reads from the registers mentioned above to access `t1` and `t2`, computes a return value, and stores that value in yet another register. Then, foo jumps back to where it was called in main.

Main then reads from the register where foo's return value was stored, and puts that value into the variable `x`.

That's a high level description of what happens with a function call. A more detailed explanation is probably too much to expect out of a stack overflow post (but maybe not).

Comment: Or the literals are saved directly at specific addresses on the stack, or inside an aligned stack frame. Or perhaps just one of them is saved on the stack. Or perhaps the calling convention dictates that the function itself is responsible for stacking parameters, so that they end up where is most convenient for the specific function. Or they aren't saved at all, perhaps the compiler optimized away or inlined the whole function. And so on.

Comment: @Lundin Sure; I was just trying to provide a basic/brief description of what a function call might typically look like.

Comment: Who does this job of loading 23, 24 into specific registers? O.S?

Comment: @gpuguy The program itself loads the values into memory. Your C program is basically translated from C to an assembly specific to your machine. The translated assembly will contain instructions that load 23, 24 into registers and then jumps to the location of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about platform for which you write the code. Different hardware and software platforms use different ABIs, i.e. way of passing parameters between calls.

Furthermore, it might be dependent on the compiler version and language dialect you are using.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

To get the answer you need to specify: hardware platform, OS version, compiler to be used and language this thing is written with (C/C++) or just calling conventions used.

Examples of differences:
On ARM some parameters can be passed via registers, and some via stack. On x86 most of the parameters are passed on the stack (with a notable exception of C++ methods), the order of arguments are defined by language and convention used and alignment is a matter of standard, or in case of M-soft, commercial specification.